# Custom Permalink Structure for terms/taxonomies of custom post type

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks

So I have a custom post type with 3 taxonomies attached to it. I want users to be able to filter custom posts based on their taxonomy choice. So I have 3 taxonomies, charity, type, location and I want to for exmaple domain.com/findby/location/los-angeles or domain.com/findby/charity/red-cross

```
   domain.com/post-type/%postname%/
   domain.com/findyby/%taxonomy%/%specific-term%/
```

I know it's doable, I'm just somewhat clueless as to how!

Answer (score 1):

Create your custom taxonomies for your custom post type and for each, set the slug to include the findby portion, as in the example below for charity.

```
     'has_archive'           => true,
     'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'findby/charity', 'with_front' => false ),
     'query_var'             => true,
     'public'                => true,
```

Create your custom post type with desired slug.

```
     'has_archive'           => true,
     'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'postname', 'with_front' => false ),
     'query_var'             => true,
     'public'                => true,

     // include all relevant taxonomies, such as category, post_tag and your custom ones
     'taxonomies'            => array('category' , 'post_tag', 'charity')
```